# Setting a custom log

Tags: macos, command-line, logs, console

I have to get all the chromium and firefox info logs out of `/var/log/system.log` and into a nice quiet `/var/log/{chromium,firefox}.log`.

However I can neither recall or find how to set that in `syslog.conf`.  How would I go about doing that?

EDIT:  I have been looking at the `asl.conf` file  for the asl logging daemon.  This seems to have something to do with what I want, although, going from syslog to a binary log format is directly against sense.

EDIT:  To be very clear one can use syslog to dynamically slice the logs. Apple is transitioning from syslog to the apple system log. So the grep approach only deals with the deprecated `/var/log` syslogd files.

Switching to syslog-ng and logging to sqlite would seem to be easier, but who knows?  I'm sure the proprietary format is the way to go.

Note that

```
syslog(1)
```

is the command line tool for the ASL database.

```
syslog(3)
```

is the C api to the syslogd daemon.  The ASL replacement for the above is

```
asl(3)
```

Now,

```
syslogd(8)
```

has 2 modules, one writing to the files defined in

```
syslog.conf(5)
```

and one writing to the apple system log, as defined in

```
asl.conf(5)
```

ASL seems to be the future. Syslogd is configured by both `syslog.conf` and `asl.conf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The situation is like that: Applications can use the syslog(3) API and the asl(3) API to log messages, other data logged can come from the kernel or from the network. All of these messages are handed over to the syslog Daemon: syslogd(8). The syslogd now outputs log messages *both* the BSD way (it writes stuff into various basic log files like /var/log) *and* into a unified log message store (/var/log/asl.log).

If you want certain log messages not to appear in your log *files* (eg. you read logs like system.log by selecting them in Console.app), you will need to configure syslog.conf(5) like [chiggsy said](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/setting-a-custom-log/8106#8106). If you want messages not to be stored in the asl database, you will need to configure asl.conf(5).

If, for example, you do not longer want Bonjour's (mDNSResponders) Log messages to be stored in the ASL db, you will need to add the following line to /etc/asl.conf :

```
? [= Sender mDNSResponder] ignore
```

… and then "gently" restart the syslogd by:

```
sudo killall -HUP syslogd
```

Now, messages from mDNSResponder will no longer appear when you go into Console.app's "all messages", but still exist within your logfiles.

Lastly, if you call syslog(1) from the command line, it acts as a nice frontend for querying the ASL db - you could for example ask it to show all messages from the Time Machine Backup starter that were logged in the last two hours by running:

```
syslog -k Facility -k Sender com.apple.backupd-auto -k Time ge −2h
```

…which explains, why the ASL db is handy: you can search for log files simultaneously in "all log files".

Comment: So, how do you figure out who the "Sender" is supposed to be?  For example, I want to see sshd stuff, I tried "sshd" and "com.openssh.sshd" and neither returned info that is clearly there in system.log

Comment: @Michael good question! Indeed I'm not sure why `syslog` behaves differently for sshd (and apparently vnc, ftp so I submitted this as a [new question here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210949).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 answers in practice, if I want to change the logging file location.

### Syslog:

Solution is to *not* read the OS X syslog.conf manpage. Read the [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syslog.conf&manpath=FreeBSD+3.1-RELEASE) one. Syslog still works this way when using its BSD module.

```
!-org.chromium.Chromium

*.notice;authpriv,remoteauth,ftp,install,internal.none  /var/log/system.log
kern.*                          /var/log/kernel.log

!*

!org.chromium.Chromium
*.*                                                 /var/log/stfu.log
!*
```

This removes chromium's ludicrously chatty log from /var/log/system.log, and puts it into stfu.log.