# Why is this AirPort+TimeCapsule disappearing from the network?

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule, macos

All was well for months, then suddenly Time Machine reported it hadn't backed up for 20 days because the disk was unavailable. When I cycle the power the Time Capsule is green in AirPort Utility, for a few hours and then it disappears again.

I've tried a hard reset on the backup device.

The AirPort is not creating a network, I'm using a Comcast router instead which the Time Capsule is wired to.

TIA for your assistance.

Comment: Similar problem here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/76382/38539 tl;dr : Time Capsules are difficult to diagnose and require fairly advanced sysadmin knowledge and scripting to do so. If it is less than a year old, take it to the store, if older you'll probably have to replace it.

Comment: Yes, sir, I did see that question; however, that capsule is being used as a wireless access point, and all of the comments/answers are related to that particular aspect. The intention here is to direct diagnostics with a different slant.