# How do I access sshd log messages that are in system.log with /usr/bin/syslog?

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, logs

I am aware that messages on OS X are usually logged in the ASL database which then (based on [asl.conf](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/asl.conf.5.html)) are also written into files like /var/log/system.log

Based on [this comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/setting-a-custom-log/8111#comment254609_8111) I tried (*and failed*) to figure out why messages from sshd are available in /var/log/system.log but are not accessible with e.g. `/usr/bin/syslog -k Facility | grep 'sshd'`

Any ideas?

Comment: strangely enough, I was able to get a couple of sshd messages to show up using `syslog -k Facility -k Sender sshd` but they were totally unhelpful different than what showed up in /var/log/system.log!